# Include python source code in header function declaration part of sphinx

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sphinx

I am new to sphinx.
The situation I am facing is that I have a complicated function and in the spphinx documentation I would like to show, some example usage of the function directly.

```
def myComplicatedFunction(status):
    """Here I have a brief description

    :param status: explanation

    :returns: explanation
    """
    <<< code >>>

    return statstics
```

Somewhere in the sphinx-part I would like to include some python code which shows example input and example output. But whatever I do (use **``** or **::**) as documentation suggest it does not get syntax highlighting. It is just included as simple text which makes reading difficult.

***How should I include python code example in sphinx?***

Comment: In [this](http://openalea.gforge.inria.fr/doc/openalea/doc/_build/html/source/sphinx/rest_syntax.html#figure-directive) example they use the directive `.. code-block:: python` and the python code is indented. But this is probably because the code does not use the `>>>/...` prompts. If you use those then you should just probably use `::` and write the code with the prompts with one indent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simulate a Python interactive session; blocks that start with `>>>` are automatically treated as Python source code:

```
def myComplicatedFunction(status):
    """Here I have a brief description

    :param status: explanation

    :returns: explanation

    >>> myComplicatedFunction('status value')
    {'foo': 2, 'bar': -400}

    """
    # Code

    return statistics
```

Comment: I tried it and it works fine, but how come >>> itself is shown in the documentation?

Comment: Because that's by design. Using a python interactive shell to document code is common practice; we use it here on SO all the time. :-) Don't use `>>> ` merely to enable syntax highlighting, use it to illustrate interactive use of your function.

Answer (score 0):

```
.. code-block:: language
      def foo()....
```

works for python, but ensure, you have pygments installed.

In the somethingconf.py configuration file these two statements are interesting:

```
pygments_style = 'sphinx'
```

and depending on the output write something like

```
options['add_syntax_highlighting'] = True
```